# Configurable configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, category, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm looking for a solution to the following scenario:

1. My store sells shirts that vary in size and color, like most clothing stores.
2. **The twist: a shirt can come with a school logo printed on it.**
3. There should be a category for each school, that contains all shirts with the school's logo on them.

A simple setup for #1 is to add the shirts as configurable products, and upload images (without the logos) to the associated simple products. **But I can't think of a way to achieve #2 & #3 - add in the product images with the logos and display them in different school categories.**

How is it done?

Is there such a thing as configurable configurable products?

Comment: Is there enough information in the below answers to close this out? If so, mark as answered. Otherwise edit and provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

**The school logo is already preprinted and you carry stock**

You're out of luck. You need this to be a configurable product pivot attribute and you need to create simple products which reflect all the properties of the physical product they represent: e.g. a *blue, medium, t-shirt with a Duke logo*.

**The shirts are printed on-demand and you just need a customer to pick a logo when adding to the cart:**

You don't need configurable products for this. You can easily take advantage of Custom Options which a dropdown type to let your customers configure which school logo.

This is handy because they can have custom pricing and even carry a "sku".

[image]

Comment: How do I add per-school images if I choose the second method?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this. From easiest to hardest: 1) Write some javascript that will output a list of images based on the names of the dropdown. E.g., duke.jpg, purdue.jpg. 2) Do something similar, but in a rewrite of the template phtml file that is responsible for the product options block.  This is potentially better because you can call Magento models and hook the images up to the option id's gracefully. 3) Create your own image custom option type, which would be based on the dropdown or radio button type (because you can only choose one).